# Create post-forms such as craigslist on my Django powered website

Tags: django, django-forms, django-users, django-permissions

I'm creating a marketplace website such as Craigslist. I'd like to make "post-forms" for users to post their own product information (by uploading photos, adding forms (name, price,condition,,etc.)) on my website' category-page.

Now,  I think I can do these things by making use of "Django Permission", but is it correct? If so, how can I do that? Or if not,  there are other ways to allow users to do these things ?

The short summary of my website is like below. Specifically,I'd like to know how to allow people to post their products on the category page.

1. Register & Login
2. You would have several categories such as furniture, books, games,,, and then, click one of those categories. (I've created this category-page by using "Django admin")
   (eg.  )
   http://bakersfield.craigslist.org/
3. Then, you can see what kinds of goods are sold on that category page. And then, At the top of website, you can find "Post" button to post our products on the top of my website.
   And after click it , you can find "Posting title" "Price" and "upload photos" and many other forms.
   (eg)
   https://post.craigslist.org/k/7v...

4.After filled those forms,then click "submit" button to post your products pages' link to category page.

Craigslist is the best example for my website.

Comment: See here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#permissions and here https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian#readme

Comment: Thank you for your answer and editing my question. However I'm sorry it seems my question wasn't clear and I couldn't ask you correctly.Therefore, I changed my question. To sum up, my question is "how to allow users to post their product information on my website's category-page. Should I learn "Django Permission" and "django-guardian" to achieve this ?

Comment: Django is a web framework. You can build any web application you can imagine. The same is true for any framework such as django. What you seem to ask is very basic. Login, forms processing, etc are the basis for any serious website. Please start with the tutorial here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: I completed those tutorials.Plus, I checked documentations of UserAuthentication,forms, views, and templates and now I'm checking this django example (http://lightbird.net/dbe/forum1.html) because this example shows the example of "post" function. However, I'm still confused about "post" function. If possible,can you give me some documentation or suggestions?

Comment: For your information, I already created "Login&Logout" and "Registration" form. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/#working-with-forms has some info on how to process forms(including POST). Also here on SO there are a lot of questions about processing forms and POST requests. If you have any specific question dont hesitate to post a question.

Comment: Thank you! According to the form documentation, I created a form.But, I'm facing a problem (please see here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149642/how-to-render-a-post-and-make-it-show-up-on-another-page). I guess the key of my problem is the knowledge of "API(especially 'get', 'pk' and  'id')" and "render" , is it correct ? I'm so confused about the conception of 'pk' and 'id'.