# How to render a POST and make it show up on another page

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, render

I'm trying to create a marketplace website similar to craigslist.
I created a form according to the Django tutorial "Working with forms", but I don't know how to render information I got from the POST forms.
I want to make information(subject,price...etc) that I got from POST show up on another page like this. http://bakersfield.craigslist.org/atq/3375938126.html and, I want the "Subject"(please look at form.py) of this product(eg.1960 French Chair) to show up on another page like this. http://bakersfield.craigslist.org/ata/  }

Can I get some advice to handle submitted information?
Here's present codes. I'll appreciate all your answers and helps.

<-! Here's my codes -->

◆forms.py

```
from django import forms

class SellForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    condition = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    body = forms.TextField()
```

◆views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from site1.forms import SellForm

def sell(request):

    if request.method =="POST":
        form =SellForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            price = form.cleaned_data['price']
            condition = form.cleaned_data['condition']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            body = form.cleaned_data['body']

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/books/')

    else:
        form=SellForm()

    render(request, 'sell.html',{'form':form,})
```

◆urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^sechand/$','site1.views.sell'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

)
```

◆sell.html

```
<form action = "/sell/" method = "post">{% csrf_token%} 
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type = "submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a `Sell` model/table in your db(where you store the users' "sells"), otherwise it wouldn't make any sense. This means you can save yourself some time and use a `ModelForm`,
instead of a simple `Form`. A model form takes a database table and produces an html form for it.

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from yourapp.models import Sell

class SellForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Sell
```

In your views.py you need one more view that displays the `Sells` that your users have
posted for others to see. You also need an html template that this view will render with context about each `Sell`.

**sell_display.html**

```
{% extends 'some_base_template_of_your_site.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div id="sell">
  <h3> {{ sell.subject }}</h3>
  <p> {{ sell.condition }}</p>
  <p> {{ sell.body }}</p>
  <!-- the rest of the fields.. -->
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

We also need a new url entry for the displaying of a specific `Sell`

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Changed `sell` view to `sell_create`
    url(r'^sechand/$','site1.views.sell_create'),
    # We also add the detail displaying view of a Sell here
    url(r'^sechand/(\d+)/$','site1.views.sell_detail'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from yourapp.models import Sell
from yourapp.forms import SellForm

def sell_detail(request, pk):
    sell = get_object_or_404(Sell, pk=int(pk))
    return render_to_response('sell_display.html', {'sell':sell})

def sell_create(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SellForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # The benefit of the ModelForm is that it knows how to create an instance of its underlying Model on your database.
            new_sell = form.save()   # ModelForm.save() return the newly created Sell.
            # We immediately redirect the user to the new Sell's display page
            return HttpResponseRedict('/sechand/%d/' % new_sell.pk)
    else:
        form = SellForm()   # On GET request, instantiate an empty form to fill in.
    context['form'] = form
    return render_to_response('sell.html', context)
```

This is enough to get you going I think. There are patterns to make these things more modular and better, but I don't want to flood you with too much information, since you are a django beginner.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I'm redirected to "Page not found (404)(URL where I'm redirected is "Http~~/sell/" because I have "<form action = "/sell/" method = "post">" inside of sell.html)" page when I click "submit" button on the POST form. According to your explanation, I should be redirected to the new Sell's display page. Should I change something in sell.html?

Comment: With the urlspattenrs I have above, the form action should be "/sechand/". Adjust accordingly to anything you like it to be.

Comment: Thanks so much and I've successfully created Registration/Login/Logout/Profile/ pages and, thanks to your information, the 'sell' page (these posted products' information are stored such as "/sechand/1/, /sechand/2/...")! Plus, I created "products" page which has some categories(books, furniture,,,etc. but now I simply focus on "electronics") to show the products-information pages we created by "SellForm(ModelForm)". However, I can't figure out how to link posted-data out of form to "electronics.html" page. If you have some free time, please check this question. ( http://bit.ly/TA7Vl2 )

Comment: @stack5914 If you feel that my answer helped you, then it is customary to `accept` it as the correct answer. I'll take a look to your other answer probably tomorrow, because I'm out of town. cheers

Comment: I accepted :) and I made my question more specific and concise . ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13224213/noreversematch-related-to-pk-django ) So if possible, please take a look at this question instead of former one.