# NoReverseMatch (related to pk) : django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, primary-key

I'd like to get posted-data from a form and display them. 
I used "{% url uasite1.views.sell_detail sell_detail.pk %}" to extract data according to their pk.

However, just [ NoReverseMatch ・・・, Reverse for 'uasite1.views.sell_detail' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.] showed up.
What's wrong with my codes?

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Sell(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    condition = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from uasite1.models import Sell

class SellForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Sell
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response,get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from uasite1.forms import SellForm
from uasite1.models import Sell
from django.template import RequestContext


def sell_detail(request, pk):
    sell = get_object_or_404(Sell, pk=int(pk))
    return render_to_response('sell_display.html',{'sell':sell})

def sell_create(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SellForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_sell = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/sechand/%d/' % new_sell.pk)
    else:
        form = SellForm()
    context['form'] = form
    return render_to_response('sell.html',context,context_instance = RequestContext(request))

def Electronics(request):
    latest_sell_list = Sell.objects.all()[:5]
    return render_to_response('electronics.html',{'latest_sell_list':latest_sell_list})
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^sechand/$','uasite1.views.sell_create'),
    url(r'^sechand/(\d+)/$', 'uasite1.views.sell_detail'),
    url(r'^electronics/$', 'uasite1.views.Electronics'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

electronics.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block extrahead %}
    <p><strong>Electronics</strong></p>

{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <p><a href="{% url uasite1.views.sell_detail sell_detail.pk %}">{{ sell.subject }}</a></p>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of mistakes.

1: Change your url

```
url(r'^sechand/(\d+)/$', 'uasite1.views.sell_detail'),
```

to

```
url(r'^sechand/(P<pk>\d+)/$', 'uasite1.views.sell_detail'),
```

This makes url to accept parameter which is passed to view through `pk`.

2: Your `Electronics()` view suggests that you are passing list to template so you need to update template to iterate over this list and render each item in list appropriately. And make sure to use variable names appropriately.

```
{% block content %}

    {%for sell in latest_sell_list %}
        <p><a href="{% url uasite1.views.sell_detail sell.pk %}">{{ sell.subject }}</a></p>

    {%endfor%}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thank you, but the result still shows "NoReverseMatch error" 
[Reverse for 'uasite1.views.sell_detail' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. ] though 【arguments'('',)'】 was changed to 【arguments '(1,)'】.  In addition, after I added "P<pk>" to my urls.py, the "sell_display" page started not working (Page not found (404) at http://localhost:8000/sechand/1/) May be something else wrong with my codes ?

Comment: After I added "?P<pk>" to my code, it successfully worked!Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Change
`<a href="{% url uasite1.views.sell_detail sell_detail.pk %}">`

to:
`<a href="{% url uasite1.views.sell_detail sell.pk %}">`

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesn't work. The display shows [Reverse for 'uasite1.views.sell_detail' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.] and [ <p><a href="{% url uasite1.views.sell_detail sell.pk %}">{{ sell.subject }}</a></p>] is highlighted in the "Error during template rendering" and, [return render_to_response('electronics.html',{'latest_sell_list':latest_sell_list})] is highlighted in the "Traceback".